# how to get started on Google Dart if I am totally new to programming?

Tags: dart

I have a bright idea that I want to develop and thus want to learn web programming. I have searched high and low only to be confused by all the JS'es and the frameworks and all the never ending pros and cons.

I have recently come across Google Dart and its somewhat reassuring to know that all I will ever need for web application development is possible and there in one place. First question if I just learned Dart would this previous statement that I don't need to learn anything else be true?

Secondly, how should one go about learning Dart? Can I learn directly, if not what prerequisites should I know first to get started on Dart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should know that all the information that interests you exists on the main site: [Dart: Structured web apps](http://www.dartlang.org/).

This site include the following information:

**Get started:**

- [Get Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/#get-started)
- [Get Tutorials](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/)
- [Technical Overview](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/technical-overview/)

**Docs:**

- [Programmer’s Guide](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/)
- [Dart API Reference](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/)
- [Language Specification](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/)
- [Dart Cookbook](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/cookbook/)
- [Dart: Up and Running](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/)
- [Books on Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/books/)
- [Articles](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/)
- [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html)

**Tools:**

- [Dart Editor](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/)
- [Pub Package Manager](http://pub.dartlang.org/)
- [More tools for Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/)

**Resources:**

- [Dart Code Samples](http://www.dartlang.org/samples/)
- [Dart Synonym: Translations from Dart](http://synonym.dartlang.org/)
- [Try Dart online](http://try.dartlang.org/)
- [Dart Presentations](http://www.dartlang.org/slides/)
- [Dartisans: The Dart show and podcast](http://www.dartlang.org/dartisans/)
- [Dart Tips: Short Video Tutorials](http://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/)
- [Dart Bug and Feature request](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list)

**Community:**

- [Contact the Dart Project](http://www.dartlang.org/support/)
- [Contributor's Guide](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Contributing)
- [Community Resources](http://www.dartlang.org/community/)

Within these resources, you can find a lot of useful information for getting started with Dart.

Also, they contains a lot of links to other external sources of information.

Comment: Thanks mezoni... when I say I am a newbie I mean I don't even know html. I have gone through the dart website extensively but some of it still went over my head. I get your point though and willlook at thetutorials etc to get started :)

Answer (score 3):

Several years ago, I started learning php. Twice. And twice did I fail, because I just read theory and did not code php itself.

If you want to learn Dart, just start developing. Think of an idea you would like to implement and start developing it. Every few lines of code you will stumble and have no clue how to solve something, and therefore you will have to read theory, ask on stackoverflow - but will always have in mind, what your precise goal is.

Time will pass, you will have implemented 2-3 ideas of yours and will have covered a great deal of Dart.

Learning by doing.

Comment: Thanks Gero for taking the time to reply. So you are saying I just wasted a bit of money on buying a programming coursein udemy ;) but seriously though thank you for the advice. Like I mentioned above I dont even know the basics like html css etc. But I will take your advice and start off with dart tutorials and as you say I have the community here to help me out :)

Comment: You did not waste anything! That money you spent, will save you so much time! Spend money to gain time - best thing since the invention of sliced bread.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't even know HTML, I suggest starting with the [Dart Tutorials](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/).

Comment: Thank you Seth for adding your answer. I realise that perhaps the middle part of my question might be a bit naive but would you be so kind to weigh in on the bit about......its somewhat reassuring to know that all I will ever need for web application development is possible and there in one place. First question if I just learned Dart would this previous statement that I don't need to learn anything else be true?